# How to copy all files from one directory to another only if file doesn't exist in destination subfolders?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a directory with files directly in it `C:\test1`.
I want to copy all these files to `C:\test2` only if the file does not exist in any subdirectory in `C:\test2`.

Need to write a Windows batch file which can do this. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried using the following, but it does not searches recursively in destination directory:

```
For %%F In ("C:\test1*") Do If Not Exist "C:\test2\%%~nxF" Copy "%%F" "C:\test2\%%~nxF"
```

Comment: Add your attempt into your question post! Anyway, instead of `if not exist "C:\test2\%%~nxF" copy ...`, try `> nul dir /S /B /A:-D "C:\test2\%%~nxF" || copy ...`.

Comment: You could use `XCopy` with an empty `/D` option, _which would only copy all files except for unchanged existing ones_. You could probably even use `RoboCopy` with the `/XN` and `/XO` options too. Enter `XCopy /?` or `RoboCopy /?` at the Command Prompt for usage information and the additional options you may require.

Answer (score 1):

Examples make it easier for everyone to understand the requirements for a task.
So let me start with an example.

Source directory `C:\test1` contains following files:

- Test1.txt
- Test2.txt
- Test3.txt

Destination directory **tree** `C:\test2` contains following directories and files:

- **Subfolder1**

  - Test2.txt
- **Subfolder2**

  - **Subfolder3**

    - Test3.txt

For this example just file `Test1.txt` should be copied to directory `C:\test2` because `Test2.txt` and `Test3.txt` exist already in subfolders of `C:\test2`.

So the directory **tree** `C:\test2` should look as follows after batch file execution:

- **Subfolder1**

  - Test2.txt
- **Subfolder2**

  - **Subfolder3**

    - Test3.txt
- Test1.txt

This can be achieved with:

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("C:\test1\*") do (
    dir "C:\test2\%%~nxI" /A-D /B /S >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 copy "%%I" "C:\test2\" >nul
)
```

It is also possible to do that with a [single command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564):

```
@for %%I in ("C:\test1\*") do @dir "C:\test2\%%~nxI" /A-D /B /S >nul 2>nul || copy "%%I" "C:\test2\" >nul
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to push ahead into PowerShell, this code might help. When you are satisfied the the files will be copied correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

Ok, I admit that I do not have a test1 and test2 directory for testing, but this will probably get you started.

```
$targetdir = 'C:\test2'

Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\test1' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ((Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $targetdir -Filter $_.Name).Count -eq 0) {
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $targetdir -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

If you save the script above as `Copy-IfNone.ps1`, then you can run it from a cmd shell using:

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\Copy-IfNone.ps1
```